# Using CurlPP with vs2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, curl, curlpp

I'm trying to build a C++ console app in VS2008 using the static curlpp library. The code - which is curlpp example 00 - is as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


#include <curlpp/curlpp.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
#include <curlpp/Options.hpp>


using namespace curlpp::options;

int main(int, char **)
{
  try
  {

    // Our request to be sent.
    curlpp::Easy myRequest;

    // Set the URL.
    myRequest.setOpt<Url>("http://example.com");

    // Send request and get a result.
    // By default the result goes to standard output.
    myRequest.perform();
  }

  catch(curlpp::RuntimeError & e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  catch(curlpp::LogicError & e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I've downloaded the source and have my include path pointed to the source include files, but when I try and compile, I get a boatload of errors in the inline files of the type:

definition of dllimport function not allowed

Surely lots of folks have used curlpp with vs2008 and I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Could someone tag this with curlpp tag, please?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at *\include\curlpp\internal\buildconfig.h* file where there are the following macros defined

```
CURLPPAPI
CURLPP_INCLUDE_TEMPLATE_DEFINITIONS
CURLPP_TEMPLATE_EXPLICIT_INSTANTIATION
```

based on values of these three macros

```
CURLPP_STATICLIB
BUILDING_CURLPP
CURLPP_SELF_CONTAINED
```

Read about them in *README.win32* file and define above three macros accordingly.
In case you still have a problem let us know.

By the way; today I put current version of curlpp for downloading 
[curlpp-current.2009.05.21](http://curlpp.googlecode.com/files/curlpp-current.2009.05.21.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Usually people get this error when they are trying to #include a library's header file with the library's "EXPORT" macro defined. curlpp must have some macro, usually found in code that looks like this:

```
#ifdef NATIVEDLL_EXPORTS
#define NATIVEDLL_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define NATIVEDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

and you have the NATIVEDLL_EXPORTS defined in the preprocessor. Remove this definition. ppcurl won't be called "NATIVEDLL_EXPORTS", it will have some name of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Piotr's answer: don't forget to build libcurl itself accordingly - dynamically or statically and define CURL_STATICLIB alongside CURLPP_STATICLIB (if building static version, of course).
And on a sidenote: I absolutely didn't like CURLPP, it was hard to understand how to make it do what I need. You might want to use pure libcurl with your own wrapper.